# Could TEMPEST-like attacks against earphones be feasible?

Tags: rf

Since [earphones and earbuds are microphones](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/274652/using-headphones-as-microphone) connected to an antenna (their cable), they could passively transmit any talk happening nearby, albeit with a very small intensity, at least in theory (please correct me if I'm wrong). However, in practice, could a *specialized* antenna a few meters away pick up the signal and distinguish it from the background noise? In other words, could earphones be used in a [TEMPEST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempest_%28codename%29) attack?

For the sake of the argument, please assume very cheap earphones with unshielded cables.

Comment: *they could passively transmit any talk happening nearby* Theoretically yes, but practically: good luck picking up that signal as it will be extremely small. Calculate the **wavelength** of the signals and then determine how effective the "antenna" will be. Also most microphones are **electret** mics which need a biasing voltage to power the amplifier inside. If that amplifier is off, there will be no signal through the cable. If something is "specialized" it does not mean that it can then do the impossible.  So no, not possible but feel free to prove me wrong by showing a working prototype.

Comment: Another issue is that microphone cable are shielded, thus nothing / not much will get actually radiated.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie If headphones are plugged in a computer, could that power the amplifier? I'm afraid I'm not knowledgeable enough in electronics and antennas to attempt working on a prototype, or even doing basic computations (I've not touched Maxwell's equations for 15 years).

Comment: @Damien Good point. I'll edit my question to limit it to cheap unshielded cables.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Are most earphones electret earphones? The question talks about earphones picking up sound, not microphones.

Comment: shielding on most headsets tends to be pretty poor, often a few strands of loosely wrapped copper (with some kind of of coating that makes it almost unsolderable), because the mic output has often already passed through a preamp and is quite low impedance. The earpiece signals hardly need shielding at all, and will probably couple more strongly onto the mic than than most background noise, due to proximity.

Comment: Given the average consumer earphone construction is probably feasible even if not cheap. Consider that the original tempest equipment was worried about reading the text on CRTs from the spurious emission of the beam control electronics…

Comment: @A.Hersean:  The fact is that at any distance you could detect the electromagnetic signal from the wires, you could just sit there and **listen**  in with your ears.  We're talking centimeters, decimeters at most for the signal from an electret microphone.  Audio wavelength electrical signals don't radiate well, and the microphone signal is **very** low power.  Next to no power in circuit that it virtually not radiated at all means there's pretty much no signal to eavesdrop on.

Comment: The earphones might pick up some sound, but that won't do any thing for anyone trying to spy on you.  Again, there's virtually no signal to radiate.  Most of what little signal there is will be short circuited.  Earphones are driven by the output of an amplifier.  The output of the amplifier looks like a short circuit to any signal coming out of the earphone.  Tiny signal shorted into nothingness, then very little of what is left can be radiated => nothing for an eavesdropper to pick up electronically.

Comment: @JRE That's what my intuition says also. But it's not a proof. Maybe directional antennas, with amplification and interferometry, could pick up something my ears could not. I'd like some number on signal to noise ratio, for example (I don't know anything about the strength of the background noise in EM audio frequencies, nor can I quantify the very tiny amount that can be radiated from earphones, if any).

Comment: It is a proof as far as I'm concerned.  The wavelength of the electromagnetic wave for a 1kHz signal (in the middle of the normal speech band) is about 300 kilometers.  A directional antenna for that wavelength would contain elements of at least 37 kilometers length.  You're not going to be building anything directional at that frequency.

Comment: @JRE Thanks. Also, it just crossed my mind that this looks like [the Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_(listening_device)) built by Theremin. Would it be possible to remotely power unplugged earphones to get a similar effect?

Comment: It does **not** resemble "the Thing."  That required power from outside at radio frequencies and a resonant chamber that resonates at the radio frequency and whose sidewalls flex enough from normal speech to vary the radio frequency resonance of the chamber.  This requires a large, flexible metal chamber wall and a chamber that resonates at radio frequencies and audio frequencies.  Nobody is going to listen in on  your conversations that way - too much hassle.  You're not going to listen in on anybody that way - too much hassle.

Comment: @JRE Thanks again. Feel free to post your thoughts as an answer :)

Comment: Old school: crystal earbuds will work like a microphone and a crystal microphone can emit sound. Crystal are the easiest to do this with but not the only ones.

Comment: @Gil this does not address the question of how that signal would end up being emitted as EM wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the way audio from an amplifier *drives* the earphone/earbud. The signal direction is from an amplifier -to- the earbuds. Compare *that* signal amplitude with the amplitude of audio *generated* by earbuds acting as microphone. One is very large while the other is thousands of times smaller. For any electromagnetic signal radiating from the cable/earbud, you must separate the tiny microphone signal from the thousand-times-larger signal.
Let's not yet consider what electromagnetic signals might radiate from this system, and consider only **separating the tiny microphone signal** from normal (much larger) earbud signal. Any old POTS telephone does this signal separation easily since two wires connecting two telephones separates two conversations so that each recipient only hears the other end, and not themselves. It is easy since both signals on the cable have similar amplitudes - your scenario (where signal ratio is huge) is far more difficult. Nevertheless, the cable to earbuds *does carry* both currents.
It might be possible to re-create the large signal exciting earbuds...for example, a radio receiver might be the signal source - a signal accessible to an eavesdropper. However, generating an *exact* copy would be very difficult. It must be exact copy: the microphone signal is the difference between copy and the large signal exciting earbuds.

Can these currents be sensed remotely?
Two wires to earbuds carry these currents out and back. Audio magnetic fields of two closely-spaced wires cancel in far-field. Most earbuds I've seen maintain close spacing along their entire length. However, it is possible that earbuds *might* be arranged to separate these two wires, especially around the head, but not likely. Separated wires might radiate a magnetic field that could be sensed remotely. But audio magnetic fields wouldn't travel far...audio through the air radiates more efficiently.

Audio exciting earbuds *might* be Class-D PWM...a common battery-saving type of audio power amplifier. The earphone cable *might* carry not just audio, but high-frequency (above 30 kHz) modulated audio. This PWM signal and its harmonics might radiate some remotely-accessible signal from the earbud cable. However, the tiny microphone signal *still* must be separated from this even-larger main PWM signal.

Consider too that earbuds in-ear are lousy microphones. Can you say, "muffled audio"?
With all these requirements/difficulties, it would be a tough task:

- to remotely-sense currents (a PWM signal might be more easily remotely-sensed).
- separate out a tiny microphone signal from a much larger signal.